# Hounded by upwork.com people after posting a job - how to handle this

Tags: freelancing

I posted a job on upwork.com about 4 hours ago, and have been inundated with people trying to contact me via my personal Skype/Gmail.  I purposefully did not post my Skype or Gmail contact info on the work request, so they are googling/guessing my contact info and reaching out to me at work, during work hours.

I've found it a little creepy as several people have figured out my personal email account and personal Skype account.  What is the best way to make everyone contact me through upwork.com?

Comment: Is your full name in your posting?

Comment: Its not in the posting, but is part of my profile, which I realized is public information to little to late.

Comment: Yes recruiters actively scan the sites for newly posted resume. Most job sites have ways for recruiters to search profiles to match a potential job applicant. The idea was to be honest but reality wise it's a huge spamming scam for recruiters to send out mass spam in hopes to get a bite. They will use whatever information you give out. Unfortunately there is little you can do. I still get calls on my parents phone for me uploading my resume to monster.com nearly 11 years ago. They always say, "I see you *jussst* uploaded and I was wondering if you're still looking for a job 5k miles away?"

Comment: It may seem creepy, but one piece of advice I see a lot for job seekers, is to contact the hiring manager directly, skipping HR or other "standard" hiring processes.

Answer (score 4):

Just state it right there and there in your upwork post, that you will only consider offers made trough the website and nowhere else.  That would make me think twice before skyping you.

Comment: Might even consider adding "unsolicited skype or direct email is an automatic 'no'" It also shows you immediately that someone hasn't read your profile very closely.

Comment: If these are automated spam this won't have any effect.

Comment: @Myles Good point. I hadn't considered scraping.